# How to create recommended ListView in flutter and fire store

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

There's a way to create a recommended from user ListView using fire base and flutter...

For example I have a list of data in firebase that I am fetching them from firebase as I show them in the data list screen, and I have a list of recommended list view from user for example the clicked data item from user something shows like the below image:

[image]

To be more specific how figure if the data was viewed by user or not?

There's a way or docs to do something like this?

Comment: This is what you are looking for? https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/contentrecommendation-android#0
And NO, there is NO flutter specific package yet for recommendation system for now its only for native android. BUT you can create your own model and integrate it with flutter.

Comment: Could you explain this: "To be more specific how figure if the data was viewed by user or not?" ? 
Are you trying to know if the user has viewed the widget?

Comment: @VictorEronmosele yes exactly I need how to figure how the user view object :)

Answer (score 1):

In case your intention is to provide some kind of "user likes" functionality.

You can create `Provider` of [ChangeNotifier](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier-class.html) with [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package at root (for example) and store `Set<YourShopItem>` there.

Then expose methods like `add(YourShopItem item)` and `remove(YourShopItem item)` on this `ChangeNotifier` which should add and remove items from your set and call `notifyListeners()` every time you call this method.

Then when you need to determine if your item is liked just obtain your `ChangeNotifier` and check if item is in set. Your widgets is gonna be updated every time `add` or `remove` methods are called because of their subscription to `ChangeNotifier` through `Provider`.

Comment: Yes but it's another case, I can fetch user data likes, but in this case I want to fetch user-data views

Comment: I'm sorry I got lost in question's formulations. Well, if you want to check "_if the data was viewed by the user or not?_" then you can track list's scroll position and mark elements which are on screen according to scroll position as viewed. Is this what you want? If yes, I can elaborate on that.

Comment: @MahmoudHarooney, is this question still actual?

Answer (score 0):

In case your intention is to track visibility of item.

You can use [visibility detector](https://pub.dev/packages/visibility_detector) package to track whether certain widget is visible. You can subscribe to certain widget and when it's shown, a callback is gonna be fired. So you should wrap every widget of your list into `VisibilityDetector` widget and save that your item was viewed.

Something like that should do the job:

```
final List<String> entries = <String>['A', 'B', 'C'];
final List<int> colorCodes = <int>[600, 500, 100];

ListView.builder(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    itemCount: entries.length,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return VisibilityDetector(
        onVisibilityChanged: (VisibilityInfo info) {
          if (info.visibleFraction == 1) {
            ON_YOUR_ITEM_IS_VISIBLE_FUNCTION();
          }
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          color: Colors.amber[colorCodes[index]],
          child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${entries[index]}')),
        ),
      );
    }
);
```

Also refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63577928/13737975.